# How to rescue the error exception raised by the `constantize` method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, rescue

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and I would like to properly rescue the following process flow by raising a "custom" error message:

```
def rescue_method
  # sample_string.class
  # => String
  # sample_string.inspect
  # => "ARubyConstantThatDoesNotExist"

  begin
    build_constant(sample_string)
  rescue
    raise("My custom error message: #{build_constant(sample_string)} doesn't exist.")
  end
end

def build_constant(sample_string)
  "AModule::#{sample_string}".constantize
end
```

*Note*: I feel "forced" to use the [`constantize`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-constantize) method also in the raised "custom" message in order to [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) code...

When the `rescue_method` is executed it seems that the `raise("My custom error message")` code is never executed and I get the following error:

```
uninitialized constant AModule::ARubyConstantThatDoesNotExist
```

How to properly display the raised "custom" message (*since a further error exception is raised in the subsequent raised "custom" message*)? What do you advice about?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that your `build_constant` method is doing two things:

1. Building the class name.
2. Turning the name into a class using `constantize`.

One of those things wants to use the other when an exception is raised. A simple solution is to pull those separate tasks apart:

```
def build_class_name(sample_string)
  "AModule::#{sample_string}"
end

def rescue_method
  name = build_class_name(...)
  name.constantize
rescue NameError
  raise("My custom error message: #{name} doesn't exist.")
end
```

You should also be more specific about the exception you're looking for so I added that for free.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't want to rely on catching any exception, you could use `safe_constantize` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Inflector/safe_constantize).

Same purpose as `constantize` but will return `nil` instead, whenever a Module does not exist.

```
'UnknownModule::Foo::Bar'.safe_constantize  # => nil
```

Answer (score 0):

```
begin
  "AModule::#{sample_string}".constantize
rescue SyntaxError, NameError => err
  raise("My custom error message")
end
```

Comment: Sorry, I've forgotten to put some important details in the question (since a further error exception is raised in the subsequent raised "custom" message...). I just updated that.